# Why does running "arraylist.get()" crashes my application in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file, arraylist

I am trying to read a file in Android Studio and place each string into an arraylist, but when I try to get the string from the arraylist the app crashes with a message of:

> message: "Unfortunately, App has stopped"

Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    String text = "";

    tv_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    File n = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\AndroidStudioProjects\\LOTOS.1\\app\\src\\main\\assets\\nouns.txt");

    //Instantiate Scanner s with f variable within parameters
    //surround with try and catch to see whether the file was read or not
    try {
        s = new Scanner(n);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Instantiate a new ArrayList of String type
    ArrayList<String> theWord = new ArrayList<String>();
   

    //while it has next ..
    while(s.hasNext()){
        //Initialise str with word read
        String str=s.next();

        //add to ArrayList
        theWord.add(str);

    }

    text = theWord.get(150);

    tv_view.setText(text);
    //return ArrayList


}
```

Comment: It runs fine in Eclipse

Comment: @ShaishavJogani The problem is that it compiles fine, no errors in the event log. However the app crashes

Comment: If it crashes, there is definitely an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you can't read file directly from your windows system in Android. Android device and windows is totally different system. Even though, you have put your file in `assets` folder, you can't read it because the path refers to the windows structure.

**Your Android device or emulator can't read this path : `C:\\Users\\Admin...`**

To access file from your `assests` in Android Studio, you should use `getAssets().open(...)` method.

Below is the example how you can read your file.

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("nouns.txt"), "UTF-8")); 

// do reading, usually loop until end of file reading 
String mLine;
while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       //process 
       ...
}
```